# Uniswap v3. Is it better solution?

Tags: ethereum, cryptocurrency, decentralized-applications, uniswap

I start to explore Uni v3 and here is what I faund.
For testing purpose I invest 33$ on ETH/USDC pool and put it in interval [500, 8000]. After one day my profit is 0,007463$....
On the other hand and if we suppose v3 is normal pool (like I invest on [0, infinity)) and according data from https://info.uniswap.org/#/pools/0x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640
(TVL=315m, fees=248k) my profit will be 33*0.248/315 = 0,026$ ?!? More than 3x greater !?!
How is possible that ?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that all liquidity is around price...And cos of that profit will distribute to more liquidity...Catch is that in my opinion Uni v3 isnt better solution cos you never know how much liquidity is around you....And I try all uni v3 calculators to see what my earnings will be and all of them give wrong data. They give big mistake in estimates.
Is it v3 better ??

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).